# fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during ZeroPadImageSections

Tags: visual-studio

I just got this error when building a windows phone project. I googled 'ZeroPadImageSections', but there's nothing!

My environment:

visual studio 2013

windows 8.1

```
3>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during ZeroPadImageSections
3>  
3>    Version 11.00.61030.0
3>  
3>    ExceptionCode            = C0000005
3>    ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
3>    ExceptionAddress         = 0022542E (001E0000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\WPSDK\WP80\bin\x86_arm\link.exe"
3>    NumberParameters         = 00000002
3>    ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
3>    ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 0000000C
3>  
3>  CONTEXT:
3>    Eax    = 00000000  Esp    = 004CE9D8
3>    Ebx    = 00000000  Ebp    = 004CE9E8
3>    Ecx    = 028502D8  Esi    = 028502D8
3>    Edx    = 00000000  Edi    = 00000002
3>    Eip    = 0022542E  EFlags = 00010246
3>    SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
3>    SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
3>    SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
3>    Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
3>    Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
3>    Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
```

How to deal with it?
thanks!

Comment: That's a hard crash, an access violation. A standard "corrupted state" exception. That could be because of a bug in the linker but that's pretty unlikely. Far more likely is corrupted file data. Thoroughly clean the build with Build + Clean. And delete any remaining .ilk and .pch files by hand. If that works then you want to worry about the health of your disk drive.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans! I removed all generated files manually, moved the solution to another disk, and rebuilt again, but it failed again. I found after it failed, the size of .ilk file is 512M. I have no idea if they has any relation.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I countered it again, and after carefully checked, I think I've found the answer.

It's because of non-exist lib in linker options.

In my solution, I have project A depends on project B. But in "Configuration properties -> Linker -> Command Line", it points to an old location of projectB.lib. I don't know why. I thought it should change automatically after I change the configuration of project B, but it didn't.

Then I remove the reference and add it again, the "full path" of the reference seems okay now, and the linker works well.